# Perform the procedure for pressing the button on the HTML page Chromium

Tags: html

I have an HTML page

```
<html>
<body>
    <button> This is a button! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

it is loaded into chromium
How to catch a user's click on it and execute code?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575450/tchromium-mouse-click

Comment: You mean you want to add JavaScript to your webpage?

Comment: I want when in TChromium you click on the button the procedure in Delphi was carried out.

Comment: You need to add a "onclick" event to that button. 

The onclick event would have to call a "javascript extension" that you registered previously and that function sends a process message to Delphi. 

The JSExtensionWithFunction demo in CEF4Delphi has all the details.